# How node IPC works between 2 processes

Tags: node.js, ipc

Using nodejs fork you can perform IPC between the parent process and the child process. Previously I was under the impression that the child process would have an extra environment variable with a file descriptor. I printed the process env but I can't see any variable with a file Id, I don't see any open sockets either, so my question is how does node IPC works behind the scenes?

Comment: If you look at [the source code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/child_process.js#L111), it looks like it's probably a named pipe.

Comment: Looking further into [more of the code](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/pipe_wrap.cc), it appears that libuv (cross platform library that node.js uses) has a [Pipe abstraction](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/pipe.html) which is a domain socket on Unix and a named pipe on Windows.

Answer (score 4):

> so my question is how does node IPC (for forked processes) works behind the scenes

The [source code for fork](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/lib/child_process.js#L111) uses a Pipe object internally.  Looking further into that [Pipe object](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/src/pipe_wrap.cc), it is a wrapper over the libuv Pipe object.  Then, looking into [libuv](http://docs.libuv.org/en/v1.x/pipe.html), it's Pipe abstraction is a domain socket on Unix and a named pipe on Windows.

Now, since this is all undocumented implementation details, there's nothing that says it has to always be done this way in the future - though one would not expect it to change unless there was a really good reason.

Comment: Then shouldn't it show up on `netstat -l` or a socket file be present? It puzzles me that I didn't saw those (maybe I overlooked)

Comment: @PauloLopes - Perhaps this will help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/270544/how-do-i-get-active-unix-domain-sockets-for-a-specific-pid-if-i-cant-use-lsof-c.  Feel free to browse around in the node.js source code yourself if you think something else is going on.  I don't have a *nix server (which I assume is the platform you're asking about) at my current location to try things myself.